# Script Code Snippet shows in Blog Post Summary

Tags: javascript, html, blogger, adsense

Recently my blog [Sample](http://asndjkaskhdf.blogspot.in/) approved Adsense and so I started placing Ads on top of the post. But this causes the ad code to show up in the post summary like this
Please see this [image: ximagex]

Please help me  to figure out how to remove that.

The Java Script Code

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
//<![CDATA[
//Post Thumbnail Setting
var TemplateismSummary = {
    displayimages: false,
    imagePosition: 'left',
    Widthimg: 200,
    Heightimg: 0,
    noThumb: 'https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/-GRP8IcURRsw/T9MjiNWXUcI/AAAAAAAAB88/QEDpDHxI55o/s1600/no-thumb.jpg',
    SummaryWords: 21,
    wordsNoImg: 20,
    skipper: 0,
    DisplayHome: true,
    DisplayLabel: true
};
```

Comment: Please send your XML code

Comment: Its a blog so how to send the xml code!!

Comment: Go to Template >Edit HTML then copy your code. you can use this site [pastebin](http://pastebin.com)

Comment: shall i paste the whole code?

Comment: Yes, If you use a custom template.

Comment: too long code !!!

Comment: I believe the java script that shows up post summary doesn't exclude the adsense script code

Comment: The problem is you can't post javascript inside of a blogger post because it's going to just try to render it as text. Adsense  code is supposed to be placed in a global area of your blogger template.

Comment: Paste the rest javascript code till </script> at least.

Comment: so any workaround to show ads inside the posts

Answer (score 0):

You will need to utilize the newly introduced `snippet` operator. This is Blogger's native method for generating a snippet from an HTML string (In our case, this is the full post content). Setting the options `linebreaks` and `links` to `false` is required to completed remove all the HTML tags from the snippet generated via this operator. Replace the instance of `<data:post.body/>` with the following code -

```
<b:if cond='data:blog.pageType not in {"static_page", "item"}'>
  <b:eval expr='snippet(data:post.body, {length: 450, linebreaks: false, links: false})' />
<b:else/>
  <data:post.body/>
</b:if>
```

For information regarding all the options of `snippet` operator -

> #### snippet(string, options)
>
> Produces a short snippet from an HTML string.
>
> **options**: Object specifying the snippeting options, which are:
>
> - **links**: boolean for whether to preserve anchors/links in the snippet.
>   Defaults to true.
> - **linebreaks**: boolean for whether to preserve linebreaks (tags) in the
>   snippet. Defaults to true.
> - **ellipsis**: boolean for whether to append an ellipsis to the end of
>   the snippet. Defaults to true.
> - **length**: Number specifying the maximum length of the snippet.